# Validation URL php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Как сделать, чтоб https://www.youtube.com/ добавлялось в базу данных, а просто набор букв или цифр нет

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="name">Official Web Site:</label>
    <input type="text" name="website" placeholder="http://yoursite.com" />
</div>
```

Сам php код, всей регистрации

```
<?php

include("database/db_conection.php");
if(isset($_POST['company_register']))
{
    $company_name=$_POST['name'];
    $company_email=$_POST['email'];
    $company_pass=$_POST['pass'];
    $company_copass=$_POST['copass'];
    $company_country=$_POST['country'];

    if($company_name=='')
    {
        //javascript use for input checking
        echo"<script>alert('Please enter the name')</script>";
        exit();//this use if first is not work then other will not show
    }

    if($company_country=='')
    {
        echo"<script>alert('Please enter the country')</script>";
        exit();
    }

    if($company_pass=='')
    {
        echo"<script>alert('Please enter the password')</script>";
        exit();
    }

    if ($company_pass != $company_copass)
    {
        echo"<script>alert('Error... Passwords do not match')</script>";
        exit;
    }

    if($company_email=='')
    {
        echo"<script>alert('Please enter the email')</script>";
        exit();
    }
    //here query check weather if user already registered so can't register again.
    $check_email_query="select * from companies WHERE company_email='$company_email'";
    $run_query=mysqli_query($dbcon,$check_email_query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query)>0)
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Email $company_email is already exist in our database, Please try another one!')</script>";
        exit();
    }
    //insert the user into the database.
    $insert_company="insert into companies (company_name,company_email,company_pass,company_copass,company_country,company_website) VALUE ('$company_name','$company_country','$company_email','$company_pass','$company_copass','$company_website')";
    if(mysqli_query($dbcon,$insert_company))
    {
        echo"<script>window.open('../index.php','_self')</script>";
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
  //some action
}
```

1. У Вас нет экранирования входных данных (даже если это админка, все равно нужно)
2. Вместо `$company_country==''` используйте `empty($company_country)`
3. Вместо того, чтобы каждый раз алертовать ошибку, лучше собирайте их в массив, `join`те его и выводите в самом конце выполнения скрипта
4. Переходите на PDO ))

Comment: а можете кинуть пример, как реализовать?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/6Gxmtvj1 на полноту решения не претендую, но в общем случае так

Comment: почему то, не отображает в бд, данные и что делать с error, чтоб ошибку показывало? Куда ее вставить в форме регистрации?

Comment: `$errors` Вы можете распечатать после формы сразу же. А почему не добавляется: на 54 строке добавьте `var_dump($errors)`, после 57 добавьте `echo mysqli_error()`

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\registration\company_registration.php on line 56

Comment: <div class="field">
<label for="name">Official Web Site:</label>
<input type="text" name="website" placeholder="http://yoursite.com" />
</div>  Я тут гдето должен вставить error? у меня просто сама форма в index.php , а пхп регистрация в company_registration.ph

Comment: Вы полностью скопировали код? Судя по ошибке где-то пропущена скобка в конструкции if. Проверьте код в нормальном редакторе с подсветкой синтаксиса, а еще лучше в IDE, например, PhpStorm

Comment: ниже вставил код, я же все правильно добавил?

Comment: точку с запятой не поставил, но оно все равно не добавляется в базу

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump($errors)
if(empty($errors)){
    $SQL=join(",",$SQL);
    echo mysqli_error()
    if(mysqli_query($dbcon,"INSERT INTO `companies` SET {$SQL}")){
        header("Location: /");
        exit;
    }else{
        $errors[]="Can't insert data to database";
    }
}
if(!empty($errors)){
    $errors=join("<br />",$errors);
    //если нужно показать ошибки асинхронно через js
    if(isset($_GET["ajax"])){
        echo $errors;
        exit;
    }//иначе проверяем массив на самой странице и выводим в нужном месте
}
```

Comment: Перенесите mysqli_error() после самого запроса и выведите сам запрос `echo "INSERT INTO `companies` SET {$SQL}";`

Comment: все равно не добавляет

Comment: Так Вы запрос покажите, я же для этого попросил вывести его

Comment: подскажите, как сделать, чтоб ошибка выводилась в html форме? Она у меня открываеться, через alert, и потом переходит на файл php.

Comment: В нужном месте добавить <?=$errors?>